# When a radical (or semiprime) ideal is prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In a commutative ring, we know that every prime ideal is radical. So I'm looking for results about the converse but I only found this: [A radical ideal in a commutative ring is prime if and only if it is not an intersection of two radical ideals properly containing it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264810/a-radical-ideal-in-a-commutative-ring-is-prime-if-and-only-if-it-is-not-an-inter)

Are there other results about when a radical ideal is prime? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $Q$ is a primary ideal, then its radical is prime.

Comment: @Watson yeah, that's true but a primary ideal is not in general a prime ideal.

Comment: I think you wanted to say that an ideal whose radical is prime is not in general a primary ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An ideal in a commutative ring is prime iff it is radical and meet-irreducible. $I$ is *meet-irreducible* if whenever $I=J\cap K$, then $I=J$ or $I=K$.

Comment: Mmm it seems that "meet-irreducible" is basically the same condition that I found in the link that's in my question, being the only diffference that we don't need $J$ and $K to be radical ideals, just only ideals, right?

Comment: Yes. If $I=\textrm{rad}(I)$ and $I=J\cap K$, then $I=\textrm{rad}(J)\cap \textrm{rad}(K)$. So if $I$ is radical, then it is meet-irreducible in the lattice of all ideals iff it is meet-irreducible in the lattice of radical ideals.